# How to find the volume of a solid of revolution?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

The region bounded by $x^2-y=0$ and $x+y=0$ is rotated around $y=1$

I solved for:
$$y = x^2 $$
and $$y = -x$$

And I then also solved for x for both of those.

I set up the integral like so:

$$ V = 2\pi\int_{-1}^0 (y-1)(-y-y^{1 \over 2})dy $$

And used $y$ as the variable to integrate by because the functions are being rotated around $y=1$.

However, I keep getting weird answers like -$17 \over 30$, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong though.

Comment: @jm324354 for what it's being rotated about? It's definitely y=1

Answer (score 1):

You are using the method of cylindrical shells. I will do it more or less like in your approach, though that would not be a first choice.

I imagine you drew a picture. It is correct to integrate with respect to $y$. But the picture makes it clear that $y$ goes from $0$ to $1$.

The radius of the shell at height $y$ is $1-y$. For the 'height" of the cylinder at $y$, note that it is $-y-(-y^{1/2})$, since for the left half of the parabola we have $x=-y^{1/2}$. It follows that the volume is
$$\int_0^1 2\pi (1-y)(y^{1/2}-y)\,dy.$$

If I were using cylindrical shells, I would note that by symmetry the volume is the same as when the region between $y=x^2$ and $y=x$ is rotated about the line $y=1$. Now I would be in my region of comfort, the first quadrant, and writing down the integral for the volume involves less chance of error. Negative numbers are trouble.

We can also do it by slicing perpendicular to the $x$-axis. Again, let's work with the region between $y=x^2$ and $y=x$. The cross-section at $x$ is a circle with outer radius $1-x^2$ with a circular hole of radius $1-x$ cut out. The volume is 
$$\int_0^1 \pi\left((1-x^2)^2-(1-x)^2   \right)\,dx.$$

Comment: If the solid was being rotated around x = 0, would the bounds change to the x-axis, so that one bound is the point of intersection between the two functions, and the other is at 0 where they intersect again?

Comment: If we are rotating about $x=0$ (the $y$-axis), **and if** we are using cylindrical shells, then the integration is with respect to $x$, from $x=-1$ to $x=0$. (Unless we decide to exploit symmetry, as I suggested.)

Comment: I don't know if you'll see thisbefore my final in an hour, but could you explain to me why with the washer method you used above, why did you use x as a variable instead of y, because I thought since it's being rotated around y=something, then you're supposed to use y as a variable?

Comment: I used it with y and didn't get the right answer, then I used x as a variable and did get the right answer so I'm wondering why it works like that

Comment: One basic thing that you remember is that with washer method, if you are rotating about the $x$-axis, you integrate with respect to $x$. Note that the $x$-axis is $y=0$, so $y$ equals something. With washer method, $y=1$ is kind of like $y=0$,, kind of like the $x$-axis.

Comment: But the thing to do really is not to try to meorize rules, but instead to remember ideas. When we are using the washer method to find the volume when we rotate about $y=1$, or about the $x$-axis, we take thin slices perpendicular to the $x$-axis, of width "$dx$", find their volumes, and "add up" (integrate). So the integration is with respect to $x$.  After all these years I still automatically draw a picture before solving a volume problem, as a guide, and remember only the most basic formulas.

Comment: This is what has been tripping me up, if it's washer method then if you're rotating x=, integrate with f(x), if it's y=, integrate f(y). But with the washer method it's backwards?

Comment: I draw the picture everytime but this is the one part of calculus that I can't seem to get good at, so far

Comment: Maybe then remember that rotating about $y=c$ is like rotating  about the $y=0$, the $x$-axis, and rotating about $x=c$ is like rotating about #x=0$, the $y$-axis.